# Map JSON data to relevant fields

Tags: 8

I have to display some data from a CRM system. I need it like following.

Let suppose I have a content type "Cars" which have following fields

```
Car ID,
Car Name,
Car Model,
Car Price
```

I am creating a node from Cars content type and want the above fields to grab data from CRM. So if Car ID is 1 then Car Name, Car Model and Price will be fetched from the CRM system.

I want to know if the data from the CRM could be available as JSON, how can we map that with these fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Drupal 8 Migrate API, which allows for setting up mappers from JSON: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview